# Mount and Blade Viking Conquest: I'm stuck in a point of the main questline (SPOILERS)

Tags: mount-and-blade, mount-and-blade-viking-conquest

So I'm playing **Mount and Blade Viking Conquest** and can't progress in main questline anymore. Actually I have 2 open quests that do not let me do anything.

First quest is the Odin's Cave quest (A Most Important Letter). Ever that I try enter in the damn cave, the game don't show options to enter, only "I need recruit more men" and "leave" options. I'm level 15 and I have already convinced Ulf to not testify against me in Assembly. I tried leave my army in the refuge to enter "alone" in Odin's Cave and also increase my army, but don't appear the option to enter.

- [Quest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DMDQ.jpg)
- [Odin's Cave options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8VPN.jpg)

The second problem happens in Under the Wing of a King quest. I have convinced Ulf to not testify against me in Assembly and I killed Sven's brother in Ulf's farm, but now I'm trying talk with Konungr Horik about it and after he invites me to talk in private, the game return to map, not following to dialog options. I did try talk with him inside Ribe, but he says to talk outside.

- [Quest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrReN.jpg)
- Dialog with Konungr Horik:
- - [Telling about Sven's brother death in Ulf's farm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5t0d2.jpg)
- - [Invite to talk in private](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgcuA.jpg)

**Addicional info:**

- Playing v2.036 but savegame started in another version that I don't remember
- [Character infos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezOPY.jpg)
- Relation with Konungr Horik is 100
- [Savefile close Odin's Cave](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p66VCNHowQQDnSuOPxJEOZqoJ9NDC9jl/view?usp=sharing)
- [Savefile close Konungr Horik](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1amXIu48XAFeiqDFyHAsG4fitxYJsUnO-/view?usp=sharing)

Can someone help me?

Comment: As beautiful as the VC story is, it has quite a lot of bugs, sadly. For Odin's Cave, I can't really remember the requirements, but try having an army of over 50. Maybe for Konungr Horik, try improving your relations with him (although at this point I think the Frisians hate you)? It's been a while, so I don't really remember all that happens.

Comment: @PlanetAlexander Thank you for reply. I solved "all" problems just changing a value in savefile manually. I used that solution: https://steamcommunity.com/app/48700/discussions/0/619573787426784139/?l=portuguese&ctp=2#c619574421218004965